# Passing Data between Activities of TabHost Control

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I have a tabhost which add tab's dynamically. My problem is updating the data in one tab with another tab values selected.

For Ex: I have two tabs named 'Search & Filter' and intents added in TabHost activity page. When i select some values from spinners like 'site & equipment' from filter tab i want to update the search tab list view with specified selection from filter tab.

I have attached my sample code. Kindly verify it and suggest me on the same.

TabHost Activity:

```
public class TabSearch : TabActivity 
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Search_WOTab);

            TabHost.TabSpec tspec;
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(this, typeof(WOSearch));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            tspec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("Search");
            tspec.SetIndicator("Search", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Search));
            tspec.SetContent(intent);
            TabHost.AddTab(tspec);

            intent = new Intent(this, typeof(WOFilter));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            tspec = TabHost.NewTabSpec("Filter");
            tspec.SetIndicator("Filter", Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.Filter));
            tspec.SetContent(intent);
            TabHost.AddTab(tspec);

            TabHost.TabChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Spinner workorder = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.sp_site);
                object Data;
                //Here always showing null to spinner control
                if (workorder!=null)
                    Data = workorder.SelectedItem;
                Toast.MakeText(this, TabHost.CurrentTab.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, remove all code that is irrelevant to the problem - it's too much.

Comment: I have updated my sample code. Kindly verify it.

Comment: Only one Tab will be displayed at the same time right ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do :

1. in the WOFilter tab :

   - when you select an element you update an app_wide var (static, sharedpref, database, as you like) let's say "wo_filter_value". That way, the WOFilter Activity don't have to know anything about the WOSearch Activity
2. in the WOSearch tab :

   - only do the initialisation code in the "onCreate" method (what's need to be one only once)
   - do the list display part in the "onResume" method, reading the updated "wo_filter_value" and filtering accordingly.

As only one tab is displayed at the same time, your activity will always have to go through the "OnResume" function before redisplaying the list after you have changed the filter on the other tab.

Comment: Ya this is good idea. But in one of my scenario that i will have 7 tab's and will have so many controls. How i can share complicated data to tabs?